# How to search case insensitive in Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to search case-insensitive in Eloquent model.

Now I am using this

```
Model::where($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $value . '%' );
```

But it is case sensitive. How can I solve this?

I also find this post [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard) but I can not use it in Eloquent model

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I suggest Upper function in this case

```
Model::whereRaw("UPPER('{$column}') LIKE '%'". strtoupper($value)."'%'");
```

like this

Comment: I think you have an extra *dot* and extra single quotes i.e. it should be Model::whereRaw("UPPER('$column') LIKE '%". strtoupper($value)."%'");

Comment: it's seems not secure

Comment: @id614515 can someone elaborate, why it is insecure and how to improve?

Comment: @Origami1024 This is NOT secure because it's susceptible to SQL injections. You should use parameter binding like this:
`Model::whereRaw('UPPER('{$column}') LIKE ?', ['%' . strtoupper($value) . '%']);`

Comment: If the above doesn't work for you. Try to specify the table e.g. `UPPER( table_name.column_name )` (no quotes around table_name.column_name)

Comment: Be careful using the above answer as that is vulnerable to sql injection. Sanitize the input first.

Answer (score 79):

If you are using Postgres, you don't need to use `UPPER`, just use `ilike` as the comparator and it will do a case-insensitive comparison.

```
Model::where('column', 'ilike', '%' . $value . '%')
```

You *do* need the `%` signs to signify the substring you're searching for.

Comment: This does NOT work on MySQL as it does not support `ILIKE`.

Comment: Worked at my PostgreSQL server.

Comment: This works ONLY for PostgreSQL but doesn't work for MySQL

Comment: 'ilike' or 'ILIKE' will not work in My SQL, for My SQL @Liga you'll need to use upper() OR lower() for making your search string case insensitve...

`select * from users where upper(first_name) / lower(first_name) like %(your string)%`

don't forget to %% and your string in between those percents, this'll help you to make search more flexible by searching substrings too...

Answer (score 16):

Didn't see this solution. so I'm posting this here.

```
DB::table('products')
   ->select('productid')                
   ->where(DB::raw('lower(product)'), 'like', '%' . strtolower($searchword) . '%')
   ->get();
```

Comment: Use of `DB::raw()` is discouraged in modern code, which is why all other answers are using `Builder::whereRaw()`.

Answer (score 8):

Laravel eloquent search is case insensitive, you don't need ilike, upper or lower functions in your query.

Just use:

```
Model::query()
    ->where('column1_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%") 
    ->orWhere('column2_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%") 
    ->orWhere('column3_name', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%") 
    ->get();
```

The orWhere part is in case you have more than one table field that you want to query

Comment: Well, that is what I'm using right now. And it works just fine

Comment: "Like" operator is case-sensitive in some cases and in other not, according to db collation, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like

Answer (score 7):

This should work.

Replace `column` and `$text`.

```
$model = Models::whereRaw( 'LOWER(`column`) LIKE ?', [ $text ] )->first();
```

Answer (score 5):

What's your collation of tables?

This is a particularity of the collation in your database, try using **latin_general_ci** or **latin_gerneral_cs**, they are the insensitive case.

But if you are trying to get this in **utf8_bin** by example, it will not run because this collation is sensitive.

All examples are running under MySql.

Comment: I am using `utf8_bin` but  I dont wont change it

Comment: So, I believe it will not be possible this search, the limitation will be in your table collation choice, any kind of switch on the code will affect this particularity. I don't try it yet, but you can create another connection with the database and on your database config PHP file, and set in that array 'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci'.

Comment: Thank you for this. I didn't know that if my table is utf8_unicode_ci, the "ci" means it is case-insensitive, so I don't need to use `ilike` or other approaches here. https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/8031/18098

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily have to convert both your keyword and the DB value to the same case (UPPER or LOWER). Rather you may simply specify "iLIKE" instead of "LIKE". Following Example returns list of model data based on category_id and importantly whether the keyword matches either first name or last name:

```
$transactions = Transaction::where('category_id', $category_id);
$transactions = $transactions->where(function ($q) use($keyword) {               
    $q->where('firstName', 'iLIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
    $q->orwhere('lastName', 'LIKE', '%'.$keyword.'%');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use BINARY

```
User::select("id", "name", "email")
                    ->where(DB::raw('BINARY `name`'), "Daniel")
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this is still a case sensitive search.

Comment: This is explicitly a case-sensitive search, the very opposite of what the question was asking.