# How to find results containing either uppercase or lowercase non-latin phrase? (PHP, MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, character, sql-like

I've got some issues with non-latin characters.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE '%{$phrase}%'
```

PHP:

```
$phrase = $_POST['phrase'];
//$phrase = strtolower/strtoupper($_POST['phrase']) made no differece
```

Demo database:

```
Asomething (in the db stored as Asomething)
asomething (in the db stored as asomething)
Äsomething (in the db stored as Ã„something)
äsomething (in the db stored as Ã¤something)
```

Either I type **a** or **A**, I get what I want - *both of results*, but...
if I type **Ä**, I get *only one result* containing uppercase. How can I get both of them?

**Edited:** I use collation utf8_general_ci

Comment: What is the collation setting?  Did you want to try `mb_` functions in php?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtolower.php  "Utf-8 All the way through"?

Comment: What charset and collation are you using in your tables? You should set it all as UTF-8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/2943403 if the duplicate doesn't fix your issue, the page can be reopened.  Now the responsibilty is yours to prove that you executed the advice all the way through.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `mb_strtolower($phrase , 'UTF-8');`

Comment: Despite my earlier posted comment, this should not be the solution.

Comment: @mickmackusa Hmmm.. It's possible to write specific function for this

Comment: If searching insensitively, re-casing seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

just lowercase your search query always.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LOWER( name ) LIKE '%{$phrase}%'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2876802/2693543

Comment: And of course use prepared statements.

Comment: yes of course... ;)

Comment: This one did nothing for me. I know about prepared, but it's not about that here. But thank you for your care.