# MySQL like query for searching substring in a database table

Tags: java, mysql, substring, sql-like

I have saved my data in my MySQL database table. I am using jTextField to take user input. I want to display the rows in jtable where the user input sub-string is a part.

Code I tried:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        try{

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/date","root","");
            String query="SELECT * FROM ok where day like '%=?%'";
            PreparedStatement prepstmt=conn.prepareStatement(query);
           prepstmt.setString(1,jTextField2.getText());   // include this for showing only particular row else remove this line
            ResultSet rs=prepstmt.executeQuery(); 
            jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

        }catch(Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }

    }
```

In my case the substring to be searched is entered by user in jTextField1 and I want to use that user input.

Please correct my **String query=""; **

Answer (score 1):

I believe the library will not replace the `?` inside strings. You need to do something like:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM ok WHERE day LIKE CONCAT('%', ?, '%')";
```

Alternately you can build the string using Java:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM ok WHERE day LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement prepstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
prepstmt.setString(1, '%' + jTextField2.getText() + '%');
```

You might want to remove `%` and `_` characters from the user supplied string.

Comment: yes its workingnow, but its showing nothing in the table after the query execution

Comment: Does the table contain the specific string? like `foo=textfieldcontentbar`? Is the `=` sign intentional?

Comment: @SamlanA removed the = sign now its working. thanks. Can you please explain the reason for the = sign?

Comment: You had it in your original code so I added it as-is!

Comment: ok. One more thing can we do anything to ignore the case of the substring its searching

Comment: if you mean to do case-insensitive select try modify query to SELECT * FROM ok WHERE LOWER(day) LIKE LOWER(?) and then do prestmt.setString

Comment: The case sensitivity of `=` and `LIKE` depends on how you have setup the database, tables and columns. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard