# Ignore Case Sensitive in SQL LIKE

Tags: php, mysql

```
$keyword = $_POST['searchKeywords'];

$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE title LIKE '%$keyword%' LIMIT 5");
```

I'm getting $keyword from the input field via POST request.And I have to type the accurate title like 'The Order' with the same case sensitive So I should type the exact way it is.Is there any way to type with any case sensitive I want like 'the order' and get the result.I will appreciate your help thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard)

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL string comparison can be case sensitive or case insensitive. This normally depends on the collation used not on operator (where, like).

[Read how case sensitivity works](https://federico-razzoli.com/case-sensitivity-in-mysql-and-mariadb-queries)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can apply that function first on the keyword variable before you use it

strtolower("Hello WORLD.");

you will get it as: hellow world.