# SQL: Match two columns containing NULL values and strings and extract only the matching rows without NULL

Tags: sql-server

I have a temp table `FileTable` as follows:

```
  ID FileNameAct                        FileNameString
  1    NULL                             SalesOrderTarget
  2    NULL                             SalesTarget
  3 InventoryMaterialTarget_20220414.xlsx   NULL
  4 InventoryTarget_20220414.xlsx           NULL
  5 SalesOrderTarget_20220412.xlsx          NULL
  6 SalesTarget_20220412.xlsx               NULL
```

**Objective:** To match the string between `FileNameAct` and `FileNameString` and take out the rows that has very close match.

So the resultant table should look like below:

```
ID   FileNameAct                       FileNameString
 1  SalesOrderTarget_20220412.xlsx     SalesOrderTarget
 2  SalesTarget_20220412.xlsx          SalesTarget
```

I am thinking in below line:

```
    SELECT X.* FROM (SELECT FileNameAct, FileNameString, 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(FileNameAct,'') LIKE '%'+ ISNULL(FileNameString,'') + '%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 
    END AS Flag     
    FROM @FileTable) X
    WHERE X.Flag=1
```

Clearly, this would not give the correct result.

Can anybody share any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-join with conditions

```
Select 
  b.id,
  a.FileNameAct,
  b.FileNameString
From @FileTable a
Join @FileTable b
On a.FileNameAct 
  like concat(b.FileNameString,'%')
Where b.FileNameString is not null;
```

Comment: Just a quick question. How to tackle "case-sensitive" situation here? Eg. in case I want to join `salesorder` to `SalesOrder_20220414` using the above technique, how to do that?

Comment: The quick fix is to use `UPPER(col_1) LIKE UPPER(col_2)`  but there are better solutions
 : see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard