# MySQL Like statement not case-insensitive by default

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like, case-sensitive

As far as I know, LIKE statements in MySQL are case-insensitive by default [as shown here](https://tecadmin.net/mysql-case-sensitive-search-with-like/).

In my case, it seems they are not, for instance `SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE '%rob%'` doesn't return anything, while `SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE '%Rob%'` returns a record whose "name" column is "Robert".

I want `SELECT * FROM users WHERE CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) LIKE '%rob%'` to return the record whose "name" column is "Robert".

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2876789/80836

Comment: @Andreas Just updated the question, seems I'm not using LOWER() correctly with CONCAT()

Comment: In the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-database.html#:~:text=To%20see%20the%20default%20character,SELECT%20DEFAULT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME%2C%20DEFAULT_COLLATION_NAME%20FROM%20INFORMATION_SCHEMA.), the says: use `SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;`  to see the current collation. If that collation contains `ci` (case-insensitive) you will NOT have to use `UPPER` or `LOWER`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I search (case-insensitive) in a column using LIKE wildcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876789/how-can-i-search-case-insensitive-in-a-column-using-like-wildcard)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(name, ' ', surname)) LIKE '%rob%'
```

Comment: But now if the user types "Rob" that query doesn't return anything

Comment: So use REGEXP « rob ». % in like needs a character.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I know, LIKE statements in MySQL are case-insensitive by default as shown here.

The information described in this article is not correct. The case sensitivity in string operations depends on the collation.

[MySQL 8.0 Reference Manual / Character Sets, Collations, Unicode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset.html).

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (txt_ai_ci VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,
>                    txt_as_cs VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_as_cs);
> INSERT INTO test VALUES
> ('GREEN', 'GREEN'),
> ('Green', 'Green'),
> ('green', 'green');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT txt_ai_ci, 
>        txt_ai_ci LIKE 'Gr%', 
>        txt_as_cs, 
>        txt_as_cs LIKE 'Gr%', 
>        txt_as_cs COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE 'Gr%'
> FROM test
> ```
>
> | txt_ai_ci | txt_ai_ci LIKE 'Gr%' | txt_as_cs | txt_as_cs LIKE 'Gr%' | txt_as_cs COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci LIKE 'Gr%' |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | GREEN | 1 | GREEN | 0 | 1 |
> | Green | 1 | Green | 1 | 1 |
> | green | 1 | green | 0 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3cdb69bf824d9f2037366f813cbb75b8)*