# Table names mangled from the command-line

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line

I've got two tables in my database. And I want to see their names from the command-line in MySQL Server.

```
mysql> show tables;
+----------------+
| Tables_in_mydb |
+----------------+
| ╨╖╨░╨║╨░╨╖╤Л         |
| ╨║╨╗╨╕╨╡╨╜╤В╤Л        |
+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

My first guess was that their names encoded with wrong charsets. I've found the next command to see character sets that i'm using

```
mysql> show variables like 'char%';
```

the output was:

```
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value
       |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8
       |
| character_set_connection | utf8
       |
| character_set_database   | utf8
       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary
       |
| character_set_results    | utf8
       |
| character_set_server     | utf8
       |
| character_set_system     | utf8
       |
| character_sets_dir       | C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\share\charsets\ |
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So seems like it's like ok here and the problem lies in other place. I've found the similar problem [charsets in MySQL replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043553/charsets-in-mysql-replication) and so my conclusion is that there's a problem with my config. So how  I should modify config to change the result ?

**SOLVED**

So the problem was really with console encoding which wrongly interpret table names. I solved it by renaming the table names into latin alphabet. As `RandomSeed` mentioned another way is changing the console encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are on a Windows console (assumed from `character_sets_dir`), the console uses the CP-850 encoding (or I am told this may differ depending on your region), and therefore does not interpret correctly the UTF-8 stream sent by the MySQL client.

You can `SET NAMES cp850` to match MySQL with your actual console encoding, if 1. the charset is available on your installation and 2. the table names' characters are supported by CP-850.

Alternatively, [change your console encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/269818/change-default-code-page-of-windows-console-to-utf-8) (solution not tested)