# How to set the table collation to utf_general_ci using doctrine2

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Today I got the following error in an application which uses doctrine2

```
Message: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'like'
```

I checked with phpmyadmin that the collation of the table is latin1_swedish_ci.

Within my application I configured doctrine to use utf8

```
$em->getEventManager()->addEventSubscriber(new \Doctrine\DBAL\Event\Listeners\MysqlSessionInit('utf8', 'utf8_unicode_ci'));
```

My database was generated via install script threw an equal configured entity manager.

How to set my table's collation to utf8_general_ci using doctrine2?

Comment: Depending on your application's requirements, consider reading [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previously I reported a Bug in [Symfony](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/2044) and later moved to Doctrine. @[elliot](https://github.com/elliot) mentioned the [problem in create database](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/MySqlPlatform.php#L328).

So in this case I guess the bug is still there. So you want to create the database manually with utf-8, then it will do the other work.

But according to Benjamin Eberlei he mentions about [postConnect](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/fcc1b20f4f415492/a80557560d189187?lnk=gst&q=utf-8%20doctrine2#a80557560d189187) event listener for MySQL which calls 'SET NAMES UTF-8'. The DBAL link he mentioned was broken, else I would have looked into it.

Hope this helps

Comment: The link to the postConnect listener seems to be iinvalid.

Comment: I have linked to the post thread in groups which @beberlei points to the DBAL. As I mentioned earlier "The DBAL link he mentioned was broken". But may be you ask in doctrine users group to him to get an answer :(.

Comment: IS it possible to get a list of all table names from the doctrine api? Than you could correct this with native queries in your install script.

Comment: @tokam , the only thing you want to do is create db in utf-8 . Doctrine will do the rest creating the collation as utf-8 general ci.

Answer (score 1):

if you use annotation use code below to set collation, engine and charset:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="temporary", options={"collate"="utf16_latin_ci", "charset"="utf16", "engine"="MyISAM"})  
* @ORM\Entity
*/
```

For yml files it's the same.