# Which default database collation for an english website?

Tags: database, magento, multilingual, collation

I am starting up my installation of Magento and just wondered what people recommend is the best collation to use for my database?

It will be an english based website, however it will more than likely include multi-lingual later on however (e.g German, French etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use

> utf8_general_ci

Answer (score 0):

Either `utf8_unicode_ci` or `utf8_general_ci` will work.

For explanations as to the differences between the two, consult

[What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

to find which will give you better results.