# Html Text-area: problems with accented letters

Tags: html, mysql, servlets, utf-8, character-encoding

When in in a text-area I write words with acceted letters  ....the application store the words in mysql with some errors
E.g. if i write `può` in my sql I have `puÃ²`

How can i solve it?

Comment: Check your database and HTML page encoding.

Comment: In my jsp page i have <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: You need to change the encoding of your mysql tables to UTF-8 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change an existing table to use the UTF-8 charset:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

To set the default charset of the database to UTF8 for tables you will create in the future:

```
ALTER DATABASE databasename CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

You can use either `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`. It is explained at [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci) that there is a difference between them in the speed and accuracy of the sorting, with `utf8_unicode_ci` being more accurate and the performance gain of using `utf8_general_ci` being very minimal.

(Also, be aware, when you are doing queries in the mysql console in the command prompt, it will not display as UTF-8 even when it is stored properly. Its a limitation of the command prompt.)

Comment: This was a missing piece in my puzzle--thanks. For anyone else there struggling with this portion, as well as reading/writing accented characters into/out of mySQL, be sure to include this last UTF-8 line after connecting: `$dbs = mysql_pconnect($dbsServer,$dbsUsername,$dbsPassword);
mysql_select_db($dbsName, $dbs);
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$dbs);`