# MySQL: 'group by' without losing marks

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
name
Smith
Smith
Perez
Pérez
```

I would like to eliminate duplicates like Smith but preserve both Perez and Pérez (e and é).
If I use 'group by' I get two rows (Smith and one of the two Perez/Pérez), but I would like to get three rows (Smith, Perez, Pérez).
It happens the same with Sjögren and Sjogren, etc.
Thanks

Comment: What charset/collation are you using?

Comment: I think changing collation to your language will help

Comment: I am using utf8/utf8_general_ci

Comment: My table is in US English but contains many foreign data as well (and from many different countries)

Comment: Here is an answer very helpful regarding sorting and charset in MySQL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci

Answer (score 1):

1)First check your table if it has utf8 charset encoding with

```
select table_name,engine 
from information_schema.tables
where table_schema = 'your_database'
```

2)Secondly , if it is not than (else skip to 3rd step),  ALTER your table (utf8 character set encoding, so it will support special character)

```
ALTER TABLE `name` CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

3) SELECT from your db with utf8 charset

```
select * from your_table group by name collate utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: so u made your table to utf charset 8 ?

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` does not distinct between e and é. You need `unicode` support.

Comment: @DanFromGermany you mean utf8mb4_unicode_ci ? what you commented in other answer ?

Comment: @CodingAnt I mean at least use `utf8_unicode_ci`, not `utf8_general_ci`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `utf8_unicode_ci` rather than `utf8_general_ci` - it uses a more accurate comparison algorithm.

Comment: I tried using utf8_unicode_ci and still not differentiating between e and é. Then I tried using utf8mb4_unicode and I got the same result: Perez and Pérez are still considered the same.