# php gets ▒ instead of æøå from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble with some character encoding/charset

I retrieve some rows from a table, 1 of which is varchar. Whenever there's æ, ø or å in the varchar column they get translated to a seemingly bogus character. Same bogus char for each of the 3.

I created the table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`account_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`mytext` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1402 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the collate or charset, but haven't been able to find anything that solved this.

Comment: make sure your html page has `<meta charset="utf-8">` set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set the charset on (at least) 3 places:

1. The document:

   ```html
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   ```

   See the [official w3c pages](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) for more information.
2. The database:

   ```sql
   ALTER DATABASE `my_database` CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
   ALTER TABLE `my_table` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
   ALTER TABLE `my_table` MODIFY `my_column` … CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
   ```

   In case you wonder, see the [difference between utf8_unicode_ci and utf8_general_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci).
3. The connection, using PHP's PDO extension with the charset in the DSN:

   ```php
   $DBH = new PDO(
       'mysql:host=http://example.com;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8', 
       'username', 
       'password');
   ```

Comment: [Declaring character encodings in HTML](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)

Answer (score 0):

While retrieving record from database set it to UTF8 it will solve your problem. Use the following code hope it'll help you

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");
$con->set_charset("utf8"); 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mytable");
```

Comment: Plase don't encourage the use of the `mysql` extensions, provide samples with either the `mysqli` extensions or `PDO`.