# Parsing XML with Unicode characters in Coldfusion

Tags: xml, parsing, unicode, coldfusion

I'm connecting to an external API using cfhttp, with the returned data in XML format.  I have no control over the API or the format it's returned in.

When the data is returned, I loop through it and do cfquery inserts into my own MySQL database, which has a UTF8 charset.

However, some of the data appears to have unicode characters (it appears it should be the £ (pound) sign, but when I cfdump the XMLParsed data, it's showing as a diamond with a ? inside).  I've attached a cropped screenshot showing part of the cfdump showing this;

[image]

The problem is the cfquery insert - when it gets to those characters, it's returning this error;

***Error Executing Database Query.***

*Incorrect string value: '\xEF\xBF\xBD10 ...' for column 'voucherTitle'* at row 1

I've tried setting the charset in the cfhttp call, but get the same result.

Is there any way I can either encode/decode these, or alternatively trim them out altogether (the data gets edited further down the line anyway, so manually adding the correct symbols isn't a huge issue).

Comment: Try including `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding = "utf-8">` on top of your ColdFusion page.

Comment: Same error unfortunately :-(

Comment: You could try replacing it with its character reference- `&#163;`

Comment: (Edit) @Lee - I recall [something similar on another thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788570/dealing-with-mysql-nativeerror-code-1366-and-sqlstate-hy000-in-coldfusion/26792514#26792514). Do your DSN settings use `characterEncoding=UTF8` or is the INSERT using `CF_SQL_NVARCHAR`?  Also, I know you said the db uses UTF-8, but be sure to verify the column charset in `information_schema.columns`.  Side note, `<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding>` is only needed when the unicode characters are literally embedded in the cfml source.

Comment: @Leigh - never in a million years would I have thought to check the column charset - I always thought it would default to whatever the DB was set to.  However, that was indeed the problem - set it to UTF8 and all works a treat! EDIT - please do post that as an answer so I can accept as the answer

Comment: @Lee - Yeah, while column charset totally makes sense, I remember overlooking it too ;-) Did you also get "MySQL NativeError Code 1366 and SQLState HY000 in coldfusion" too? If so, it is probably better to just mark this as a dupe and link it to the existing answer, since the answer is the same :)

Comment: @Leigh - no, I didn't get those errors oddly

Comment: *always thought it would default to whatever the DB was set to* According to the docs, the final charset and collation [depend on what values were used in the DDL statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-table.html). Most likely the IDE used to create the tables uses a different default value for collate and/or charset default than the one you have set at the database level, ie utf8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** As of MySQL 5.5.3, there is also [UTF8mb4 which is often recommended over UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci).

---

(From the comments)

I recall [something similar on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26788570/dealing-with-mysql-nativeerror-code-1366-and-sqlstate-hy000-in-coldfusion/26792514#26792514). Double check the collation and character set for that column using the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html) view:

```
 SELECT  *
 FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'YourTableName'
```

If it is not UTF-8, you can change it using the ALTER TABLE command. Modify the column size `M` as needed.

```
 ALTER TABLE YourTableName 
    MODIFY YourColumnName VARCHAR(M) 
    CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

**NB:** If the data is important, always make a backup of the table before applying any modifications.

See also: [11.1.15 Character Sets and Collations Supported by MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html)