# Why setting a collation for UTF8 text data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I work with human-generated text which I download from different online datasets like GitHub Torrent, Twitter API, web-scraped HTML pages, Google BigQuery for GitHub etc. which means I have tens and hundreds of millions of text in the databse.

In which scenarios I should be setting a **collation** for **UTF8 fields** and **UTF8 tables** in MySQL databases? Is it necessary at all, cannot I simply use **"CHARACTER SET UTF8"**?

What are the differences between *utf8 - default collation*, *utf8_unicode_ci*, *utf8_general_ci* and *utf8_general_mysql500_ci*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every textual column has a collation. It may be set explicitly in the table definition, or it may simply be set from the table's default, the database's default, or the server-wide default. But it has a collation.

The collations you mention are all *case-insensitive.* That is, they ignore the difference between upper- and lower- case letters.  If you want case-sensitive collations use `utf8_binary`.

You probably want to use `utf8_unicode_ci` in a modern server. Read this for background.  [What's the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

`utf8_general_mysql500_ci` is a collation specifically for backward compatibility to older versions of MySQL.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-21.html

Comment: Another discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#utf8_collations .   That section is followed by examples of where ORDER BY differs, then a section on the details of many utf8 collations -- what characters are ordered differently.