# Use accent sensitive primary key in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, encoding, primary-key, diacritics

### Desired result :

Have an accent sensitive primary key in MySQL.

I have a table of unique words, so I use the word itself as a primary key (by the way if someone can give me an advice about it, I have no idea if it's a good design/practice or not).

I need that field to be accent (and why not case) sensitive, because it must distinguish between, for instance, `'demandé'` and `'demande'`, two different inflexions of the French verb "demander". I do not have any problem to store accented words in the database. I just can't insert two accented characters strings that are identical when unaccented.

### Error :

When trying to create the `'demandé'` row with the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `corpus`.`token` (`name_token`) VALUES ('demandé');
```

I got this error :

```
ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry 'demandé' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

### Questions :

- Where in the process should a make a modification in order to have two different unique primary keys for "demande" and "demandé" in that table ?

**SOLUTION** [using 'collate utf8_general_ci'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34388168/5419761) in table declaration

- How can i make accent sensitive queries ? Is the following the right way :
  `SELECT * FROM corpus.token WHERE name_token = 'demandé' COLLATE utf8_bin`

**SOLUTION** [using 'collate utf8_bin'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34388015/5419761) with WHERE statement

- I found that i can achieve this point by using the `BINARY` Keyword (see this [sqlFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99787/1)). What is the difference between `collate` and `binary`?
- Can I preserve other tables from any changes ? (I'll have to rebuild that table anyway, because it's kind of messy)
- I'm not very comfortable with encoding in MySQL. I don't have any problem yet with encoding in that database (and I'm kind of lucky because my data might not always use the same encoding... and there is not much I can do about it). I have a feeling that any modification regarding to that "accent sensitive" issue might create some encoding issue with other queries or data integrity. Am I right to be concerned?

### Step by step :

Database creation :

```
CREATE DATABASE corpus DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Table of unique words :

```
CREATE TABLE token (name_token VARCHAR(50), freq INTEGER, CONSTRAINT pk_token PRIMARY KEY (name_token))
```

Queries

```
SELECT * FROM corpus.token WHERE name_token = 'demande';
SELECT * FROM corpus.token WHERE name_token = 'demandé';
```

both returns the same row:

```
demande
```

Comment: I found a way using the BINARY keyword. It seems to work in this [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/99787/1). Is this the good way to do what I asked ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Collations**. You have two choices, not three:

`utf8_bin` treats all of these as *different*:  `demandé` and `demande` and `Demandé`.

`utf8_..._ci` (typically `utf8_general_ci` or `utf8_unicode_ci`) treats all of these as the *same*:  `demandé` and `demande` and `Demandé`.

If you want only case sensitivity (`demandé` = `demande`, but neither match `Demandé`), you are out of luck.

If you want only accent sensitivity (`demandé` = `Demandé`, but neither match `demande`), you are out of luck.

**Declaration**. The best way to do whatever you pick:

```
CREATE TABLE (
    name VARCHAR(...)  CHARACTER SET utf8  COLLATE utf8_...  NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(name)
)
```

**Don't change collation on the fly**. This won't use the index (that is, will be slow) if the collation is different in `name`:

```
WHERE name = ... COLLATE ...
```

**BINARY**. The *datatypes* `BINARY`, `VARBINARY` and `BLOB` are very much like `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, and `TEXT` with `COLLATE ..._bin`.  Perhaps the only difference is that text will be checked for valid utf8 storing in a `VARCHAR ... COLLATE ..._bin`, but it will not be checked when storing into `VARBINARY...`.  *Comparisons* (`WHERE`, `ORDER BY`, etc) will be the same; that is, simply compare the bits, don't do case folding or accent stripping, etc.

Comment: In 8.0, see `utf8mb4_..._as_ci`

Comment: In MySQL 8.0.2 they introduced a new collation called utf8mb4_0900_as_ci ("as" = accent sensitive, "ci" = case insensitive). To date, this is the only collation that is accent sensitive and case insensitive.

Comment: Note that utf8mb4_0900_as_ci does not collapse trailing whitespace in VARCHAR types.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need this

_ci in a collation name=case insensitive

If your searches on that field are always going to be case-sensitive, then declare the collation of the field as utf8_bin... that'll compare for equality the utf8-encoded bytes.

`col_name varchar(10) collate utf8_bin`

If searches are normally case-insensitive, but you want to make an exception for this search, try;

`WHERE col_name = 'demandé' collate utf8_bin`

[More here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-collation-implementations.html)

Comment: I'm going to give it a try. What would be the difference with stating BINARY keyword ? What happens if, accidently, i store data encoding with something else than utf8 ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
mysql> SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE t1
-> (c1 CHAR(1) CHARACTER SET UTF8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES ('a'),('A'),('À'),('á');
Query OK, 4 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT c1, HEX(c1), HEX(WEIGHT_STRING(c1)) FROM t1;
+------+---------+------------------------+
| c1   | HEX(c1) | HEX(WEIGHT_STRING(c1)) |
+------+---------+------------------------+
| a    | 61      | 0041                   |
| A    | 41      | 0041                   |
| À    | C380    | 0041                   |
| á    | C3A1    | 0041                   |
+------+---------+------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Could you explain a little what it does ? What is the difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_bin ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci