# Content Type Character Set in PHP Header of JSON Data for utf8_unicode_ci - Ajax Call

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, json, ajax

I'm using **utf8_unicode_ci** for a Column in MYSQL Table to store TAMIL Language Characters.

I'm Implementing an AngularJS Project, in that I'm calling the PHP Service, the return type is a JSON Data. I Can't able to get the actual Characters, instead of that I'm getting **?????????**.

My PHP Sample Source Code:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$outp = "";

$sql_select = "";
$sql_select .= "SELECT * FROM poll_quest WHERE qid = $nqid LIMIT 1 ";
$bQuery = mysql_query($sql_select, $link);
while ($bRow = mysql_fetch_array($bQuery)) {

    $qflag = true;

    $outp .= '{ "ID": ' . $bRow['qid'] . ',';
    $outp .= '"Ans":"' . $bRow['ans_tam'] . '" }';
}

$outp ='{"records":['.$outp.']}';
echo($outp);

?>
```

My Tamil Words are

- மோசம்
- மோசமாக இல்லை
- நன்று
- மிக நன்று

The MySQL Table Structure Snapshot:

[image]

The MySQL Table Data Snapshot:

[image]

The Output JSON Data Snapshot:

[image]

```
{
   "records":[
      {
         "ID":"1",
         "Ans":"??. ????????"
      },
      {
         "ID":"2",
         "Ans":"??. ?????????"
      },
      ........
      {
         "ID":"5",
         "Ans":"??. ??????????"
      }
   ]
}
```

Kindly assist me, how to get the actual characters in the Response JSON...

Comment: If you just print what you get ?  I mean... using echo with header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: @Boctulus - Refer the The Output JSON Data Snapshot, I got this in the Browser.

Comment: Try using mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8') after connect to your DB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first the MySQL driver i.e. mysql_* has been deprecated in favour of PDO or MySQLi a while back. With that said, lets move on.

The answer to you need to set the character set on the connection i.e. you will need to do the following to make it work -

```
<?php
...
$link = mysqli_connect(...);
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link); // This is your answer
...
```

For future reference, I have reworked the above code to use MySQLi to help  you out a bit -

```
<?php
// NOTE : I prefer using PDO but I have used mysqli for this example
// NOTE : The following code HAS NOT BEEN TESTED!

header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

// Connection information
$link = new mysqli($host, $user, $password, $dbname);

$link->set_charset('utf8'); // This is important or mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link) if you insist on using mysql_*

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf('Connect failed: %s\n', mysqli_connect_error());

    exit();
}

$outp = '';

// Always use prepared statements!!
if ($stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT qid, ans_tam FROM poll_quest WHERE qid = ? LIMIT 1')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $nqid); // user 's' if this is a string for the first parameter

    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt->bind_result($qid, $ans_tam);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $qflag = true;

        $outp .= '{ "ID" : ' . $qid . ', "Ans" : "' . $ans_tam . '" }';
    }

    $stmt->close();
}

echo('{"records":[' . $outp . ']}');
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the only thing you miss is

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

even though you have set `utf8_unicode_ci` for tables or fields, the connection to your database is not necessarily automatically set to use `utf8` character encoding.

---

NB: You should consider using [utf8mb4_unicode_ci instead of utf_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci), and you should really consider to set the caracter set and collation on database (at least table) level not field level (I see you have `latin1_swedish_ci` as default indicating your entire database is `latin1_swedish_ci`.