# utf8mb4_unicode_ci is slow in sorting, how will I fix that?

Tags: mysql, utf8mb4

I read this [difference between utf8_general_ci and utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

and @thomasrutter said that `utf8_unicode_ci` is slow when it comes to sorting. Then my question is how will I fix that. So I can improve the sorting speed while using `utf8_unicode_ci`. I want to transfer my collation in `utf8mb4` that's why I am curious.

**EDIT**

It is not the same, what my question here is how to fix the slow sorting of `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and I dont have ask question here what is the difference between `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and `utf8mb4_general_ci`. Please, reconsider.

Comment: No it is not, what my question is how to fix slow sorting in `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` not comparing it to `general` one

Comment: How to fix slow sorting... is too broad... it still does not fit SO guidelines.

Comment: There is a difference between "it is slower" and "it is slow."  It is slower by comparison because it is more complicated to sort, for the same reason that sorting case-intensive is slower than sorting binary -- there are more rules.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot thanks, I read a post in stackexchange.com that it takes 10s to sort a small table, so that's why I am hesitating to use `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: There are a lot of people who don't understand database indexes.  [Use the Index, Luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/) -- then it becomes largely irrelevant how long it takes to sort, because the database simply reads from the index, which is already sorted -- the sorting is done at insert/update, not select, and so any added processing cost is amortized over time to the point that it becomes uninteresting.

Comment: "10s to sort a small table" -- I don't believe it; can you provide a link?

Comment: If you need the `unicode` collation, use it.