# In searching words containing German umlauts(ä,ö,ü) I get search results only if I use 'o' in place of 'ö'

Tags: mysql, collation

I have a web application which uses mysql.I am using mysql 5.5 and my charset is UTF-8 and collation is utf8_general_ci.I have an issue where if I search for term like Jöhn in my web application I don't get any result,although there is an entry in database as Jöhn.The string is stored correctly in the database.I get the result if I search with 'o' instead of 'ö' (i.e)if I give search term as 'john' I get 'jöhn' in search result.I don't have any other entry like john.The only entry is using the german umlaut i.e jöhn.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between utf8\_general\_ci and utf8\_unicode\_ci](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Comment: Please had the `HEX()` of the various Johns.

Answer (score 2):

Let me walk through the possible situations...

The single character `ö` (hex `C3B6`) is usually treated as the same as `o` in most collations, including `utf8_general_ci`.  You can see this in

```
SELECT 'o' = 'ö' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;  --> 1 (meaning True)
```

See [*utf8 collations*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html) . 8 other collations (bin, danish, icelandic, swedish, estonian, turkish, hungarian, and german2) treat them differently.

There is at least one way to write `ö` as two characters: `UNHEX('CC886F')` is a 'combining diaeressis' plus 'o'.

```
SELECT UNHEX('CC886F') = 'o' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci; --> 1
SELECT UNHEX('CC886F') = 'o' COLLATE utf8_general_ci; --> 0
```

Back to the question...  If the `ö` is really two characters, then you do need utf8_unicode_ci.  If you can get the HEX, check against the hex I listed above.

Probably the only way for "if I search for term like Jöhn in my web application I don't get any result,although there is an entry in database as Jöhn" to happen is the two renderings of the character.

(So I agree with Robin, but I hope this illuminates the "why".)

Comment: Even after changin to utf8_unicode_ci,the issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use collation `utf8_unicode_ci`. This should solve the problem.