# Cannot add foreign key constraint - Yii 2 controller

Tags: php, yii2

I am trying to create a database table using controller method. Each time I run my code, I get the following Error Message.
I am using Yii2 Framework

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>   The SQL being executed was: CREATE TABLE `auth_item` ( `name`
>   varchar(64) not null, `type` int not null, `description` text,
>   `rule_name` varchar(64), `data` text, `created_at` int not null,
>   `updated_at` int not null ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   ENGINE=InnoDB Error Info: Array (
>       [0] => HY000
>       [1] => 1215
>       [2] => Cannot add foreign key constraint )
>
> Caused by: PDOException
>
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
>
> in
>   /home/offneo/Projects/MODULEMANAGER/Product/Software/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/db/Command.php
>   at line 844

Here is my code in controller method `actionInstall`

```
$db = Yii::$app->db;
$tableOptions = null;
$status = true;

if ($db->driverName === 'mysql') {
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci
    $tableOptions = 'CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB';
}

// Table auth_rule
if ( $db->getTableSchema('auth_rule') === null ) {
    $status &= (bool) $db->createCommand()->createTable('auth_rule', [
                    'name' => 'varchar(64) not null',
                    'data' => "text",
                    'created_at' => "int",
                    'updated_at' => "int",
                    'PRIMARY KEY (name)'
            ], $tableOptions)->execute();
    $status &= (bool) $db->createCommand()->createIndex('name_UNIQUE', 'auth_rule', 'name', true)->execute();
}

// Table auth_item
if ( $db->getTableSchema('auth_item') === null ) {
    $status &= (bool) $db->createCommand()->createTable('auth_item', [
                    'name' => 'varchar(64) not null',
                    'type'=>'int not null',
                    'description' => 'text',
                    'rule_name' => "varchar(64)",
                    'data'=>'text',
                    'created_at' => 'int not null',
                    'updated_at' => 'int not null'
            ], $tableOptions)->execute();
    $status &= (bool) $db->createCommand()->addPrimaryKey('name_pk', 'auth_item', 'name')->execute();
    // $status &= (bool) $db->createCommand()->addForeignKey('fk_auth_item_auth_rule1_idx', 'auth_item', 'rule_name', 'auth_rule', 'name', 'SET NULL', 'CASCADE')->execute();
    // $status &= (bool) $db->createCommand()->createIndex('fk_auth_item_auth_rule1_idx', 'auth_item', 'name', false)->execute();
}
```

Comment: It may be caused by non matching data type of PK and FK column

Comment: Have you tried executing the generated SQL directly on your database? It will most likely not be a direct problem with Yii2.

Comment: tried but no luck.