# Go insert on MySQL Database with special characters

Tags: go, phpmyadmin, centos7

I have the following problem:

I'm making an `INSERT INTO` with Golang, but for some reason, it's not inserting the special characters correctly (IE: `ñ`).

This is the SQL sentence:

```
ins, err := db.Prepare("INSERT INTO historico_twitter_instagram( texto_encontrado,
                        busqueda_realizada, id_usuario, link, total_reacciones, 
                        total_negativas, total_positivas, total_neutras, fecha_publicacion,
                        id_red_social,is_falso_positivo,ID_comentario) 
                        VALUES "+ fmt.Sprintf("%s",buscado))
```

Right above it I have a print to show in console what is supposed to insert, and it shows this:

```
INSERT INTO historico_twitter_instagram( texto_encontrado, busqueda_realizada,
            id_usuario, link, total_reacciones, total_negativas, total_positivas,
            total_neutras, fecha_publicacion,id_red_social,is_falso_positivo,ID_comentario)
     VALUES ('Test: ñ','@wtonki','999','','1','0','0','1','2017-10-24 00:00:00.0','2','1',
             '922923057840144384')
```

But in phpMyAdmin it's replacing the `ñ` character for other characters like `Ã±`

The strange part is, if I execute that SQL manually, it inserts okay. Any ideas?

PS: The table structure has utf8_general_ci
PS2: Sorry for my bad English! :(
PS3: The SQL is executed on Go with `_, err = ins.Run()`

Comment: [I would try utf8_unicode_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/766809/whats-the-difference-between-utf8-general-ci-and-utf8-unicode-ci)

Comment: Could you check locales, connection settings for all apps? Possibly one where in the middle the letter gets corrupted. Have you tried to insert the row manually with console tool `mysql`?

Comment: I already tried inserting the row manually with mysql console, and it inserts okay. I have other table that has exactly the same structure and it has no problemas inserting data with ñ characters on it via Golang

Comment: Use placeholders and bind your values. Never use Sprintf. That may already fix your problem, because now the driver will take care of encoding the strings. https://play.golang.org/p/PGPB6VyBLI