# How does InnoDB store character columns?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb, utf8mb4

This Question addresses only how 'short' `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` columns are stored in an InnoDB table.

- Does a `CHAR(10)` column occupy exactly 10 bytes?
- What happens with trailing blanks?
- What about character sets that need more than 1 byte per character?
- How does `VARCHAR(10)` differ from `CHAR(10)`?
- `EXPLAIN` implies that all indexed varchars contain a 2-byte length field.  Is it really 2 bytes?  Or might it be 1 byte?  (cf `key_len`).
- What about different `ROW_FORMATs`?

Not covered in this Question (to keep it from being too broad):

- What about `TEXT`.
- What about 255, 191, off-page storage, etc.
- What happens in an index starting with a char/varchar.  (Think: removal of common prefix.)
- What happens with char/varchar when involved in a `MEMORY` temp table.  Also, what changes happen in version 8.0.
- `ROW_FORMAT` has a significant impact on longer string columns, primarily in deciding when off-page storage is used.

Comment: if I get this right: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-row-format-overview.html varchar is stored on an overflow page and the char will be on a normal page. But I guess your want more in depth info

Answer (score 2):

From MySQL [Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/char.html):

The difference between `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` values is the way they are stored, `CHAR (10)` requires 10 bytes of storage no matter how many characters you use because the data is right-padded with spaces, `VARCHAR (10)` only takes 1 byte (in 1 byte character set) + length prefix (1 when the length is 255 or less, 2 otherwise... I don't know why key_len for `EXPLAIN` add 2 bytes)

I don't understand what you mean with trailing blanks, although I can imagine you are referring to the excess of trailing spaces, with `VARCHAR` these are truncated with a warning, meanwhile in `CHAR` columns these spaces are truncated silently, this has some sense cause `CHAR` are stored with trailing blanks at the end.

Regarding character set in this [link](https://adayinthelifeof.nl/2010/12/04/about-using-utf-8-fields-in-mysql/) you can see that the number of characters for the `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` is the same, although, your storage will require from 1 to 4 bytes per character, [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-charsets.html) is the list of supported character set and [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) the bytes per character.

What I've read of different rows format for [InnoDB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-physical-record.html)

**Redundant Row Format Characteristics**:

> Internally, InnoDB stores fixed-length character columns such as CHAR(10) in a fixed-length format. InnoDB does not truncate trailing spaces from VARCHAR columns.

> InnoDB encodes fixed-length fields greater than or equal to 768 bytes in length as variable-length fields, which can be stored off-page. For example, a CHAR(255) column can exceed 768 bytes if the maximum byte length of the character set is greater than 3, as it is with utf8mb4.

**COMPACT Row Format Characteristics**:

> - Internally, for nonvariable-length character sets, InnoDB stores
>     fixed-length character columns such as CHAR(10) in a fixed-length
>     format.
>
>   InnoDB does not truncate trailing spaces from VARCHAR
>     columns.
> - Internally, for variable-length character sets such as utf8mb3 and
>     utf8mb4, InnoDB attempts to store CHAR(N) in N bytes by trimming
>     trailing spaces. If the byte length of a CHAR(N) column value exceeds
>     N bytes, InnoDB trims trailing spaces to a minimum of the column
>     value byte length. The maximum length of a CHAR(N) column is the
>     maximum character byte length × N.
>
>   InnoDB reserves a minimum of N bytes for CHAR(N). Reserving the
>     minimum space N in many cases enables column updates to be done in
>     place without causing fragmentation of the index page. By comparison,
>     for ROW_FORMAT=REDUNDANT, CHAR(N) columns occupy the maximum
>     character byte length × N.
>
>   InnoDB encodes fixed-length fields greater than or equal to 768 bytes
>     in length as variable-length fields, which can be stored off-page.
>     For example, a CHAR(255) column can exceed 768 bytes if the maximum
>     byte length of the character set is greater than 3, as it is with
>     utf8mb4.
>
>   ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC and ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED handle CHAR storage in
>     the same way as ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT.
>
> ...
>
> DYNAMIC and COMPRESSED row formats are variations of the COMPACT row format and therefore handle CHAR storage in the same way as the COMPACT row format

Comment: The link to "About using UTF-8 fields in MySQL" is mostly still correct (8 years later), but needs updating to reflect `utf8mb4` and `ROW_FORMATs`.  And MySQL 8.0 is moving away from fixed-length for temp storage.

Comment: As for the "2" that `EXPLAIN` says (when it should be "1"), that's `EXPLAIN` being too lazy to get the exact length for the hidden length field.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that explain why is not considering the lenght for the lengh prefix bytes.

Comment: The final link in this answer is broken, possibly due to a change to the docs since this answer was written. There are, however, some other sources for the same prose findable on Google (e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.1-en/innodb-table-and-index.html, plus third parties, some honest and some shady, that have either archived or plagiarised it). Based on those sources, I've done my best to figure out what's a quote and what's not, and mark up each distinct quote with its own quote block. However, this answer could still do with the link fixing and the formatting improved.