# MySQL comparing UTF-8 strings

Tags: mysql

I have created a table AddictionText.

```
CREATE TABLE `AddictionText` (
`Condition` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL);
```

It's filled with UTF-8 characters, such as

```
INSERT INTO AddictionText VALUES ('šarec')
```

When I compare it with the word **s**arec I still get a single hit. I was expecting no results.

```
select * from AddictionText where AddictionText.Condition='sarec'  --mind you, first character is S not Š
```

Can someone please help me out, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with `CREATE TABLE AddictionText (...) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Comment: @sp00m that's the stuff, thank you so much! I'd accept your answer as the correct one (if you post it I'll do it) but I can only upvote it.

Comment: Evert's answer points you to it, I just proposed a collation from the ones available ;) See also https://mysqlserverteam.com/new-collations-in-mysql-8-0-0/ if you're using MySQL 8  (e.g. `utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci` might suit better). Other good reads: https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/1225328 (plus its comments) on `unicode` vs `general` and `utf8` vs `utf8mb4`, and https://www.monolune.com/what-is-the-utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci-collation/ on `ci` vs `cs` and `ai` vs `as`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is 'equal' in strings depends on language and culture, and this is true for MySQL as well.

I don't know what language `šarec` is, but to me searching for 'Sarec' and getting a result makes sense.

If that's not the case for you, you want to look for a 'collation' that better matches your expectations.

MySQL documentation has more information:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html

Comment: The desired result would be no results at all, the first characters are not the same (s and š). I'll take a look at collation, ty.