# UTF-8 encoding error for mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, encoding, urlencode

I am making a form for (Chinese) users to fill in the name. Its a php app, using mysqli, my code is like this:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "test", "test", "db");

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
if (!$link->set_charset("utf8")) {
    printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", $linki->error);
} else {
    printf("Current character set: %s\n", $link->character_set_name());
}
// someone told me to do this.

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")
{
        echo "POST";
        $displayname=$_POST["displayname"];
        $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO user(name) VALUES (?)");
        //var_dump($stmt);
        $stmt->bind_param('s',$displayname);
        $stmt->execute();
        #echo "Success create user";
        printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
        # Here's the output, when I filled the form;
        # Current character set: utf8 POSTError: Incorrect string value: '\xE4\xBD\xA0\xE5\xA5\xBD' for column `db`.`user`.`name` at row 1.
        # curl cant work either.
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <body>
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); ?>" method="post">
          <input name="displayname" type="text" id="displayname">
    <label for="displayname">chinese</label>
  </div>
<button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And i got sth like this

Current character set: utf8
POSTstring(6) "首先"
Error: Incorrect string value: '\xE9\xA6\x96\xE5\x85\x88' for column `db`.`user`.`name` at row 1.

What I am thinking is that since the var_dump result is correct, so its sth to do with prepared statement.

UPDATE: when i tried to manually urlencode the data to Displayname=%E5%BC%A0%E4%B8%89 and curl post it, the results were correct.

Comment: Sounds like your database management system or the client are not in UTF-8 mode.

Comment: Check table collation, column collation that really is UTF-8. I recommended use [`utf8mb4_unicode_ci`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/766996/128761). However, your code works fine for me. It inserted correctly without any error.