# Ruby, Rails: mysql2 gem, does somebody use this gem? Is it stable?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I found [mysql2 gem](http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2). It works fine with ruby 1.9 and utf8 encoding (as opposed to mysql gem).

But I have doubts. Does somebody use this gem in production? What about the performance test? Is it faster than mysql gem? Is it stable?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`mysql2` is meant as a more modern *replacement* for the existing `mysql` gem, which has been stale for a while now. I also heard that the author isn't supporting it anymore and instead recommends everyone use his pure-ruby version since it's compatible with more Ruby implementations (but is *much* slower).

The first issue with the `mysql` gem is it doesn't do any type casting in C, it gives you back ruby strings which you then have to convert into proper ruby types. Doing that in pure-ruby is extremely slow, and creates objects on the heap that never needed to existing in the first place. And as we all know, Ruby's GC is it's primary reason for it's slowness. So it's best to avoid it and do as much in pure C as you can.

Second is that it blocks the *entire* ruby VM while connecting, sending queries and waiting for responses, and even closing the connection. `mysqlplus` definitely helps with this issue, but only for sending queries as far as I know.

`mysql2` aims to solve these problems while keeping the API extremely simple. `Eric Wong` (author of Unicorn) has contributed some awesome patches that make nearly everything non-blocking and/or release the GVL in Ruby. The `Mysql2::Result` class implements Enumerable so if you know how to use an Array, you know how to use it.

I'm only aware of a few people using it in production right now but it is being evaluated at Twitter, WorkingPoint and UserVoice too.

I'm also in talks with `Yehuda` about it being the recommended/default for Rails 3 when it ships. Some of its techniques and optimizations are also going to be brought into DataObjects' `do_mysql` driver soon as well.

The ActiveRecord driver should be pretty solid at the moment. All you should need to do is have the gem installed, and change your adapter name in database.yml to `mysql2`.

If you're interested in using it, give it a try. I'm quick to push fixes if you find any issues ;)

Comment: Thank you for full answer!

I will try to use mysql2 gem in production! It sounds very pretty. :) 

P.S. I have found an issue: http://github.com/brianmario/mysql2/issues#issue/25 . It's about rake db:drop in rails3 project :)

Comment: Could you post what your experience was like? Did it work as a drop-in replacement? Any performance/stability issues?

Answer (score 11):

mysql2 is now the default in rails 3

Answer (score 5):

A bit late - but I'm using mysql2 in production on a couple of sites, and have found it very stable since some issues with connections getting closed were resolved a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone wants to use the mysql gem instead of the mysql2 gem in Rails 3.0.0 for Windows, I wrote a short article that explains [how to tweak the rails app generator](http://noteslog.com/post/netbeans-6-9-1-ruby-1-9-2-rails-3-0-0-mysql-gem-2-8-1/).

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you convert your 'latin1' characters to 'utf8', following the answer here:**

[UTF8 MySQL problems on Rails - encoding issues with utf8_general_ci](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346092/utf8-mysql-problems-on-rails-encoding-issues-with-utf8-general-ci)

Answer (score 0):

FYI, When using mysql2 (0.2.x) with Rails 3.0.11 I had to downgrade my version of RubyGems from 1.8.15 to 1.8.10.  Otherwise Passenger barfs...