# Ruby 1.9 field returning ASCII encoding even though UTF8 specified

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9

I have UTF-8 everywhere so why does Page.last.url.encoding return "ASCII-8BIT"?

My database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  username: root
  encoding: utf8
  database: recipebook
```

mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `pages` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recipe_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `html` blob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of mysql gem do you use? 2.8 is not ruby 1.9 encoding-aware. You can monkey patch it using [the instructions here](http://gnuu.org/2009/11/06/ruby19-rails-mysql-utf8/). [Mysql2](http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2) should be encoding-aware, but I'm not sure it works on Rails 2 (which version of rails do you use, by the way?)

Comment: SO question about mysql2: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001243/ruby-rails-mysql2-gem-does-somebody-use-this-gem-is-it-stable