# What is mysql2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
$rails new twitter -d mysql
```

then
the

> database.yml

looks like

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: twitter_development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password:　root
  host: localhost
```

So, i am sonfused why adapter is mysql2? not mysql?
is this gonna be a problem? I need to change it back to mysql or leave it here?
Thanks.

Comment: @ghayes I am not sure. I afraid in other codes there are also mysql2. It will make it worse.

Comment: Well, is your server booting correctly?  These are the only settings which specify the database server to connect to.  You could possibly need other files / gems configured to properly connect to the database, but you can easily see this by trying to boot your server (or running `rake db:migrate` from the command prompt).

Comment: Okay, I found mysql2 here.http://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*mysql2* is the modern successor of the *mysql* gem. Don't worry, this will work fine for all current MySQL versions.

More here: [Ruby, Rails: mysql2 gem, does somebody use this gem? Is it stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3001243/ruby-rails-mysql2-gem-does-somebody-use-this-gem-is-it-stable)

Answer (score 2):

The adapter is `mysql2` as that is the gem you will be using to connect. There are two gems, `mysql` and `mysql2`. The correct gem to use for Rails 3 is `mysql2`.