# Having trouble loading 'mysql' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've started writing a Ruby script which will be called as part of `rake db:seed`, and it looks like this:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mysql'
```

When I try to run it, I get:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- mysql
```

However, I can use `require 'mysql'` from within irb, and I can do this:

```
$ gem query --local | grep mysql
mysql (2.9.0)
```

Does anybody know what's up?

e: for fun, I put `puts Gem.path` at the top of my script, and got:

```
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
/home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
```

Compare that to `Gem env`:

```
 - /usr/local/rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
 - /home/vagrant/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
```

No dice.

Comment: Unrelated but I think you should use mysql2 instead http://stackoverflow.com/a/3003679/2033014

Comment: That's useful. I'm curious to see if this magically fixes the original issue somehow.

Comment: No, sadly, it didn't fix the original issue. I appreciate the recommendation, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered. I had to add the following lines in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2'
```

After that, I ran `bundle install` and it worked.