# script to convert mysql dump sql file into format that can be imported into sqlite3 db

Tags: sqlite, mysql

I have an export SQL file containing tables and data from MySQL and I want to import it into a Sqlite 3 DB.

What is the best way to do that?

Just importing the file via the sqlite3 tool doesn't work.

Comment: I've built a docker container for the sequel one liner database conversion https://blog.chib.me/how-to-convert-databases-with-one-line-of-code/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This shell script help you

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "x$1" == "x" ]; then
   echo "Usage: $0 <dumpname>"
   exit
fi
cat $1 |
grep -v ' KEY "' |
grep -v ' UNIQUE KEY "' |
grep -v ' PRIMARY KEY ' |
sed '/^SET/d' |
sed 's/ unsigned / /g' |
sed 's/ auto_increment/ primary key autoincrement/g' |
sed 's/ smallint([0-9]*) / integer /g' |
sed 's/ tinyint([0-9]*) / integer /g' |
sed 's/ int([0-9]*) / integer /g' |
sed 's/ character set [^ ]* / /g' |
sed 's/ enum([^)]*) / varchar(255) /g' |
sed 's/ on update [^,]*//g' |
perl -e 'local $/;$_=<>;s/,\n\)/\n\)/gs;print "begin;\n";print;print "commit;\n"' |
perl -pe '
  if (/^(INSERT.+?)\(/) {
     $a=$1;
     s/\\'\''/'\'\''/g;
     s/\\n/\n/g;
     s/\),\(/\);\n$a\(/g;
  }
  ' > $1.sql
cat $1.sql | sqlite3 $1.db > $1.err
ERRORS=`cat $1.err | wc -l`
if [ $ERRORS == 0 ]; then
  echo "Conversion completed without error. Output file: $1.db"
  rm $1.sql
  rm $1.err
    rm tmp
else
   echo "There were errors during conversion.  Please review $1.err and $1.sql for details."
fi
```

Comment: Hi, When I run this script, I get error because it doesnt understand fi in if. I changed #!/bin/sh to #!/bin/sh, which gets around it. But the script just deletes the sql dump file and writes an empty .db file.

Comment: Here is a slightly updated and Mac-tested version: https://gist.github.com/741043

Comment: I needed to add the following two lines after the "grep -v ' PRIMARY KEY ' |" to make it work:
grep -v '^LOCK TABLES' |
grep -v '^UNLOCK TABLES;' |

Other than that, works great!  Thanks!

Comment: This script did work for me. However, I had a problem with the SQL itself, the dump contained values like 'foo\'s bar' which sqlite couldn't read.

Comment: I've had to add more to it - AUTO_INCREMENT was in upper case, there ere DEFAULT CHARSET settings and ENGINE settings too.

Answer (score 7):

To get the above script to work, I made the following changes:

1. run it with #!/bin/bash
2. add two seds to the list of pipelined seds:

   - sed 's/\\r\\n/\\n/g'
   - sed 's/\\"/"/g'
3. the 'rm tmp' line is a no-op (unless you have a file named 'tmp' lying around :O )
4. my mysqldump command looked like this:

   $ mysqldump -u usernmae -h host --compatible=ansi --skip-opt -p database_name > dump_file

Then it worked nicely... thanks for the script.

Answer (score 5):

I tried some of these scripts that uses sed or awk, but always occurs an error, probably due to the indexes and foreign keys of my MySQL db and the mysqldump options needed.

Then I found the Perl module [SQL::Translator](http://search.cpan.org/~jrobinson/SQL-Translator-0.11010/) "that converts vendor-specific SQL table definitions into other formats..."
This module create all foreign keys and correct the indexes, changing the names if necesssary.

So, I rewrite the shell script, including the dump of the MySQL db. 
There are two dumps because the script "sqlt" only generates the structure and works fast if the dump has no data. 
Note that it can be adapted to others conversions suported by the SQL::Translator.

After I posted this shell script I realized that the question is about to convert a MySQL dumpfile,
so I did a Perl script that do that, using the module SQL::Translator. In my tests, I used a dumpfile generated without options (*mysqldump -u user --password database > dumpfile*). 
I had no problems with character sets.

In other test I had problem with mysql triggers, so I altered the scripts to skip it.

```
#!/bin/sh
#===============================================================================
#         USAGE: ./mysql2sqlite.sh <MySQL_database> <user>
#   DESCRIPTION: Converts MySQL databases to SQLite
#                Triggers are not converted
#  REQUIREMENTS: mysqldump, Perl and module SQL::Translator, SQLite 
#===============================================================================
if [ "$#" = 2 ]; then
    USER="$2"    
else
    echo "Usage: $0 <MySQL_database> <user>"
    exit
fi
if [ -s $1.db ]; then
    read -p "File <$1.db> exists. Overwrite? [y|n] " ANS
    if [ "$ANS" = "y" ] || [ "$ANS" = "Y" ] ; then
        rm $1.db 
    else 
        echo "*** Aborting..."
        exit
    fi
fi   
# extracts the necessary structure for SQLite:
mysqldump --skip-triggers --skip-add-locks --routines --no-data --compatible=ansi \
    --compact -u $USER --password $1 > /tmp/$1_$$_str.sql
# verify
if [ ! -s /tmp/$1_$$_str.sql ]; then
    echo "*** There are some problem with the dump. Exiting."
    exit
fi
# translates MySQL syntax structure to SQLite using the script "sqlt" of the
# perl module SQL::Translator (that corrects the foreign keys, indexes, etc.)
sqlt -f MySQL -t SQLite --show-warnings /tmp/$1_$$_str.sql \
    1> /tmp/$1_$$.sqlite 2> /tmp/$1_$$_sqlt.log
# verify
if [ ! -s /tmp/$1_$$.sqlite ]; then
    echo "*** There are some problem with the sql translation. Exiting."
    exit
fi
# adds statements to allow to load tables with foreign keys:
echo "PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;" >> /tmp/$1_$$.sqlite
echo "BEGIN TRANSACTION;" >> /tmp/$1_$$.sqlite
# extracts the data (simple inserts) without locks/disable keys, 
# to be read in versions of SQLite that do not support multiples inserts:
mysqldump --skip-triggers --no-create-db --no-create-info --skip-add-locks \
    --skip-extended-insert --compatible=ansi --compact -u $USER \
    --password $1 >> /tmp/$1_$$.sqlite
# adds statements to finish the transaction:
echo "COMMIT;" >> /tmp/$1_$$.sqlite
echo "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;" >> /tmp/$1_$$.sqlite
# correct single quotes in inserts
perl -pi -e ' if (/^INSERT INTO/) { s/\\'\''/'\'\''/g; } ' /tmp/$1_$$.sqlite
# load the sql file and generate the SQLite db with the same name 
# of the MySQL database
sqlite3 $1.db < /tmp/$1_$$.sqlite 2> /tmp/$1_$$sqlite.errlog
# verify
ERRORS=`cat /tmp/$1_$$sqlite.errlog | wc -l`
if [ $ERRORS = 0 ]; then
    echo "* Conversion complete. Verify the file < $1.db >"
    rm /tmp/$1_$$*
else
    echo "*** There are some problem. Verify the files < /tmp/$1_$$* >"
fi
```

Here the Perl script to convert a dumpfile in a SQLite database file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
#===============================================================================
#        USAGE: ./mysql2sqlite.pl <MySQL_dumpfile>
#  DESCRIPTION: Converts MySQL dumpfile to SQLite database
#               Triggers are not converted
#               The dump must be done with
#               > mysqldump --skip-triggers -u [user] --p [database] > dumpfile
# REQUIREMENTS: Perl and module SQL::Translator, SQLite
#===============================================================================
use strict;
use warnings;
use Carp;
use English qw( -no_match_vars );
use SQL::Translator;
use 5.012;

my $file = $ARGV[0];
my $filedb = $file;
$filedb =~ s/\.*[^.]*$/.db/;
if ( -s $filedb ) { 
    say "*** Ja existe o arquivo < $filedb >. Abandonando...";
    exit;
}
my @stru;
my @data;

open( my $SQLFILE, "<", $file )
    or croak "Can't open $file: $OS_ERROR";
while (<$SQLFILE>) {
    # nao considera linhas com comentarios e lock/unlock/drop
    next if ( /^--/ || /^\/\*/ || /^lock/i || /^unlock/i || /^drop/i );
    # processa os inserts
    if (/^(INSERT.+?)[(]/) {     
        my $ins = $1;            # captura o nome da tabela
        s/\\[']/''/g;            # substitue aspas simples - \'
        s/[)],[(]/);\n$ins(/g;   # divide multiplos inserts
        push( @data, $_ );
    }
    # processa a estrutura
    else { push( @stru, $_ ); }
}
close($SQLFILE);

my $strusql = join( '', @stru );
my $datasql = join( '', @data );
#open( my $STRU,   ">", "stru.sql" ); # to verify the results
#open( my $DATA,  ">", "data.sql" );
#print $STRU  $strusql;
#print $DATA  $datasql;

# here the conversion
my $translator = SQL::Translator->new(
    no_comments       => 0,
    show_warnings     => 0,
    quote_table_names => 1,
    quote_field_names => 1,
    validate          => 1,
);
my $struout = $translator->translate(
    from => 'MySQL',
    to   => 'SQLite',
    data => \$strusql,
    # filename => $file,
) or croak "Error: " . $translator->error;

# define inicio e final da transacao de inserts
my $prgini = "PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;\n";
my $traini = "BEGIN TRANSACTION;\n";
my $trafin = "COMMIT;\n";
my $prgfin = "PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;\n";

#gera o arquivo final sqlite
my $sqlout = join( "\n", $struout, $prgini, $traini, $datasql, $trafin, $prgfin);
open( my $FINAL, ">", "/tmp/final.sql" );
print $FINAL $sqlout;

# Monta o SQLite database
my $log = "/tmp/sqlite.errlog";
my $command = "sqlite3 $filedb < /tmp/final.sql 2> $log";
system($command) == 0 or die "system $command failed: $?";
if ( -s $log ) { 
    say "*** Houve algum problema. Verifique o arquivo < /tmp/sqlite.errlog > "; 
}
else { 
    say "*** Conversao completa. Verifique o arquivo < $filedb > "; 
}
```

Comment: I had problems with above shell script, but this perl program works perfectly!

Comment: Unfortunately for me this perl script causes an infinite memory leak and my entire system grounds to a halt within seconds.
(The file I'm trying to edit is the POD database, from http://www.product-open-data.com/download/)

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue with the mysql db being ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1).  When did the conversion to sqlite3 assumed the data was UTF-8 resulting in decoding errors.

It was easy to fix with this:

iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t UTF-8 mysql_dump_file > mysql_dump_file_utf8

Incase this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

When the sqlite3 database is going to be used with ruby you may want to change:

```
tinyint([0-9]*)
```

to:

```
sed 's/ tinyint(1*) / boolean/g ' |
sed 's/ tinyint([0|2-9]*) / integer /g' |
```

alas, this only half works because even though you are inserting 1's and 0's into a field marked boolean, sqlite3 stores them as 1's and 0's so you have to go through and do something like:

```
Table.find(:all, :conditions => {:column => 1 }).each { |t| t.column = true }.each(&:save)
Table.find(:all, :conditions => {:column => 0 }).each { |t| t.column = false}.each(&:save)
```

but it was helpful to have the sql file to look at to find all the booleans.

Answer (score 1):

At least, with mysql 5.0.x, I had to remove **collate utf8_unicode_ci** from mysql's dump before importing it to sqlite3. So I modified the script to include the following to the list of seds:

`sed 's/ collate utf8_unicode_ci/ /g' |`

Update:

MySQL treats boolean fields as "tinyint(1)", so I had to add the following **before** `tinyint([0-9]*)` sed:

`sed 's/ tinyint(1) / boolean /g' |`

Also, since I'm trying to replicate a mysql db (production) to a sqlite3 db (development)  of a Ruby On Rails application, I had to add the following line in order to set an auto-incrementing primary key:

`sed 's/) NOT NULL/) PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL/g' |`

I'm still trying to figure out a way to change the **KEY** entries from mysql to its corresponding **CREATE INDEX** entry of sqlite3.

Answer (score 1):

To convert databases with BLOBs in them I added --hex-blob to the mysqldump command and the following to the list of pipelined seds:-

```
sed -e "s/,0x\([0-9A-Z]*\),/,X'\L\1',/g" |
```

this replaces the mysql hex dump strings e.g. 0x010A…. with X’010a…’ for importing with sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

This is the best written  and well documented shell Script  to convert ssql to .db

https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776

or better use this tools It's *amazing and fast* **ESF Database Migration Toolkit** .

after having tried all the script here it didn't work until i did use the esf tool .

Note :

> ```
> Trial version add a 'T' to the begingn of each text value you have 
>  But the pro version worked like a charm :)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

works fine on Centos 5.3 64bit. once you have the output file load it like so:

shell> sqlite3 file_name.db
SQLite version 3.3.6
Enter ".help" for instructions
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file

---

0    main             /current_directory/file_name.db
sqlite> select * from table;
.
.
.
.
.
results...
sqlite>.quit