# How to migrate Django models from mysql to sqlite (or between any two database systems)?

Tags: django, django-models, database-migration

I have a Django deployment in production that uses MySQL.

I would like to do further development with SQLite, so I would like to import my existing data to an SQLite database. I

There is a shell script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489277/script-to-convert-mysql-dump-sql-file-into-format-that-can-be-imported-into-sqlit) to convert a general MySQL dump to SQLite, but it didn't work for me (apparently the general problem isn't easy).

I figured doing this using the Django models must be much easier. How would you do this? Does anyone have any script to do this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use

```
manage.py dumpdata > your_file.json
```

to export your data from the production system ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata)).

Then move the file on the development system and run

```
manage.py loaddata your_file.json
```

You can also put the file in your_app/fixtures folder with name "initial_data.json" and it will be automatically loaded when you run "manage.py syncdb" ([docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata)).

Comment: in my scenario I'm using Mezzanine and django in a python virtualenv. In order for these commands to work for me, I had to add  "python" at the start. For example `python manage.py dumpdata > db_mezzanine_bak.json`

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `manage.py dumpdata > datadump` and then when the new database is set up correctly, use python `manage.py loaddata datadump`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have contenttypes in installed app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
)
```

Use script like what for copying you entry to new base:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

    def run():

        def do(Table):
            if Table is not None:
                table_objects = Table.objects.all()
                for i in table_objects:
                    i.save(using='slave')

        ContentType.objects.using('slave').all().delete()

        for i in ContentType.objects.all():
            do(i.model_class())
```

See full manual [here](http://macrotoma.blogspot.com/2012/10/solved-move-django-from-sqlite-to-mysql.html)

Comment: I think you forgot to mention to something. Here is the things worked for me  1) Ensure correct settings (ie. if no contenttypes add it). then `python manage.py syncdb --database slave` or `python manage.py migrate --database slave`. 2) Write the function `run()` some where. 3) Call it from `python manage.py shell` or create a django custom command (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/)[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/] and use it.

Comment: That's pretty outdated answer. Latest Django have better version of  `dumpdata`, so you don't need to make custom solution for switching between DB's.

Comment: IMHO and based on my experience with my current project, I don't think so. I tried dumpdata and loaddata in Django 1.8 to convert from PostgresQL to Sqlite, which ended up in error. Your solution is working like a charm. Anyway, user should first try dumpdata and loaddata first, then they might try this too (just like me).

Comment: Neither dumpdata/loaddata nor this little routine works with me. The problem is caused by foreign keys that link to table entries that do not yet exist. Obviously the order of tables matters. It would be a great idea to add to this routine a function that postpones tables with foreign keys. I have no idea how to test tables for fields with foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe give south a try:

http://south.aeracode.org/docs/index.html

Comment: south is best suited for schema migration, not for import/export data

Comment: @mosta: the schema migration features of south are excellent, but south also has good data migration capabilities.