# Populate development database with production database values

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sqlite, migration, capistrano

I'm wondering how I could populate my development SQLite database with my values from the production server (MySQL) in an easy way. Is there a nice "railsy" way for doing this? (capistrano or something like that maybe?)

Comment: "Silently" dropping database and importing in from scratch isn't an option (can be fast and easy when using `mysqldump | mysql`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following script to convert mysqldump format to sqlite3:
[script to convert mysql dump sql file into format that can be imported into sqlite3 db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489277/script-to-convert-mysql-dump-sql-file-into-format-that-can-be-imported-into-sqli)

Then just take a look at the following articles to write your own capistrano tasks:

- [Production data to development](http://blog.robseaman.com/2008/12/2/production-data-to-development)
- [Capistrano Task For Loading Production Data Into Your Development Database](http://www.blog.bridgeutopiaweb.com/post/capistrano-task-for-loading-production-data-into-your-development-database/)