# Reading a file.sql and create the database

Tags: linux, sqlite

I have a file called *schema.sql*, which looks like this:

```
drop table if exists codes;
create table paste_codes (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    codetitle string not null,
    codebody string not null,
    pub_date string not null
)
```

Is there any way I can tel sqlite3 to read it from this file and create the database for me?
Something like cat schema.sql > sqlite3 /tmp/database.db?

Thanks

Comment: Just so you know: The SQL file instructs the creation of a table, not a database. There's a big difference.

Comment: Might want to take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489277/script-to-convert-mysql-dump-sql-file-into-format-that-can-be-imported-into-sqli (don't know of an easier way)

Comment: Oh, I thought a simple way of piping would do the job, a whole sh code! Thanks buddies! Simon, thanks, I will take a better look on that!

Answer (score 0):

I got this fixed. 
I changed the code to:

```
drop table if exists paste_code;
create table paste_code (
    id integer primary key autoincrement,
    codetitle string not null,
    codebody string not null,
    pub_date string not null
);
```

and I simply:

```
$ sqlite3 /tmp/database.db < schema.sql
```

And everything started working perfect!