# Beginner Ruby on Rails: Migrating an existing psql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

So basically I am making a new sample application that will run using an external Postgres database and a model, both created by another programmer who has given me this project.

I am supposed to create a rails app that will implement the model and database in order to add some mapping functionality. The problem is that I truly do not know how to migrate an existing database using the "db_name.sqldump" file they provided me. I have installed psql, created a new rails app and added the "pg" gem, but I haven't been able to create a table with all the model information.

I am not sure if I am being clear but I truly am pretty much lost here with RoR. Any input would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you've a pg_dump file, import it from the command line using either of psql or pg_restore.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgrestore.html

Comment: This is the answer, I had not checked back until now, but that is what I did.

Answer (score -2):

Follow this railscast by Ryan Bates - http://railscasts.com/episodes/342-migrating-to-postgresql

To convert your sqldump to a sqlite db, Follow these guides : -

[script to convert mysql dump sql file into format that can be imported into sqlite3 db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489277/script-to-convert-mysql-dump-sql-file-into-format-that-can-be-imported-into-sqli)

http://code-n-fold.com/2011/11/28/convert-mysql-dump-to-sqlite-format/

Comment: The railscast shows how to create a new database if I am not mistaken, I just want to know how to use an existing one based on an ".sqldump" file. I know its probably very similar, yet I don't know how to do it.

Comment: First convert you sqldump into a sqlite database and then use the taps gem as shown to import everything.

Comment: Pardon for asking, but how does turning a PostgreSQL dump into an SQLite dump help in importing the original dump into a PostgreSQL database?

Comment: Where does he state that he has a PostgreSQL dump and not a SQLite dump?

Comment: I beg to ask the same about SQLite. He mentions "an external Postgres database and a model, both created by another programmer"

Comment: But there's no reason to export to SQLite. If he has a PostgreSQL dump, he should restore the data using the same engine.

Comment: Yeah,  I actually figured this out myself later, I had to run the script by using a psql command and it basically created itself.