# Translating Perl to Python

Tags: python, perl, url-rewriting

I found this Perl script while [migrating my SQLite database to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql/25860)

I was wondering (since I don't know Perl) how could one rewrite this in Python?

Bonus points for the shortest (code) answer :)

**edit**: sorry I meant shortest code, not strictly shortest answer

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

while ($line = <>){
    if (($line !~  /BEGIN TRANSACTION/) && ($line !~ /COMMIT/) && ($line !~ /sqlite_sequence/) && ($line !~ /CREATE UNIQUE INDEX/)){

        if ($line =~ /CREATE TABLE \"([a-z_]*)\"(.*)/){
                $name = $1;
                $sub = $2;
                $sub =~ s/\"//g; #"
                $line = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $name;\nCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $name$sub\n";
        }
        elsif ($line =~ /INSERT INTO \"([a-z_]*)\"(.*)/){
                $line = "INSERT INTO $1$2\n";
                $line =~ s/\"/\\\"/g; #"
                $line =~ s/\"/\'/g; #"
        }else{
                $line =~ s/\'\'/\\\'/g; #'
        }
        $line =~ s/([^\\'])\'t\'(.)/$1THIS_IS_TRUE$2/g; #'
        $line =~ s/THIS_IS_TRUE/1/g;
        $line =~ s/([^\\'])\'f\'(.)/$1THIS_IS_FALSE$2/g; #'
        $line =~ s/THIS_IS_FALSE/0/g;
        $line =~ s/AUTOINCREMENT/AUTO_INCREMENT/g;
        print $line;
    }
}
```

Some additional code was necessary to successfully migrate the sqlite database (handles one line Create table statements, foreign keys, fixes a bug in the original program that converted empty fields `''` to `\'`.

I [posted the code on the migrating my SQLite database to mysql Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql/1067365#1067365)

Comment: Is this that hard to read? This is probably the most readable perl program ever written.

Comment: says a lot about perl ;)

Comment: @John Kugelman I think it would have been even more readable without the `$line` variable.

Comment: what does =~ mean in perl? it's very hard to google :(

Comment: Yea, $line is a waste of typing effort!

Comment: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/littperl/perlreg.htm here you find about =~ and other regex operators in perl.

Comment: @Jim Robert: From `perldoc perlop`: "Binary "=~" binds a scalar expression to a pattern match." Have a look at: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html

Comment: how do you not use line? a shorter variable name? combine it all into one regex?

Comment: @Jim Robert: $_ is by default assigned to when you just say while(readline()); $_ is also the default variable matched against if you don't use =~.  But "real" programs don't do that.

Comment: You can only upvote once; Cant give "bonus points" ;)

Comment: -1: No Sample Code, no attempt to translate, nothing.  Sigh.

Comment: Actually this looks like a Perl beginner wrote it, first of all warnings, and strict aren't applied, and that huge `if` statement could be better written.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here's a pretty literal translation with just the minimum of obvious style changes (putting all code into a function, using string rather than re operations where possible).

```
import re, fileinput

def main():
  for line in fileinput.input():
    process = False
    for nope in ('BEGIN TRANSACTION','COMMIT',
                 'sqlite_sequence','CREATE UNIQUE INDEX'):
      if nope in line: break
    else:
      process = True
    if not process: continue
    m = re.search('CREATE TABLE "([a-z_]*)"(.*)', line)
    if m:
      name, sub = m.groups()
      line = '''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %(name)s;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %(name)s%(sub)s
'''
      line = line % dict(name=name, sub=sub)
    else:
      m = re.search('INSERT INTO "([a-z_]*)"(.*)', line)
      if m:
        line = 'INSERT INTO %s%s\n' % m.groups()
        line = line.replace('"', r'\"')
        line = line.replace('"', "'")
    line = re.sub(r"([^'])'t'(.)", r"\1THIS_IS_TRUE\2", line)
    line = line.replace('THIS_IS_TRUE', '1')
    line = re.sub(r"([^'])'f'(.)", r"\1THIS_IS_FALSE\2", line)
    line = line.replace('THIS_IS_FALSE', '0')
    line = line.replace('AUTOINCREMENT', 'AUTO_INCREMENT')
    print line,

main()
```

Comment: I love getting code in answers... I always learn something new :)

Comment: Always happy to answer with code when feasible -- most concise and least ambiguous way, after all!-)

Comment: I could be wrong, but shouldn't it be line.replace('THIS_IS_FALSE', '0')

Comment: I thought Perl was supposed ot be hard to read. This is way harder the Perl is intuative by comparison.

Comment: @martin this is a translation... there are better ways to do it in python

Comment: @Jim - And ergo there are much better ways of doing it in Perl

Comment: In the lines using regular expression substitution, the insertion of the matched groups must be double-escaped OR the replacement string must be prefixed with r to mark is as regular expression:

    line = re.sub(r"([^'])'t'(.)", "\\1THIS_IS_TRUE\\2", line)

or

    line = re.sub(r"([^'])'f'(.)", r"\1THIS_IS_FALSE\2", line)

Also, this line should be added before print:

    line = line.replace('AUTOINCREMENT', 'AUTO_INCREMENT')

Last, the column names in create statements should be backticks in MySQL. Add this in line 15:

      sub = sub.replace('"','`')

Comment: Obviously, comments are not treated as markdown, so I'll create a new answer.

Comment: `if any(s in line for s in ['BEGIN TRANSACTION','COMMIT', 'sqlite_sequence','CREATE UNIQUE INDEX']): continue` could be used instead of `process = False ... if not process: continue`

Comment: Thanks, this is run like so for example (save the snippet to run.py for example):
1$: sqlite3 campaign.sqlite .dump > backup.dmp
2$: python run.py backup.dmp > backupinmysql.dmp
3$: mysql -h server -p -u username databasename < backupinmysql.dmp

Comment: I added
    
    line = re.sub(r"(CHECK\s+\(.+?\))([^,]+)(,?)", r"\2 \1\3", line)

because MySQL doesn't seem to like CHECK before DEFAULT.

Comment: Folks, you must include the reserved words backticking as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql

Comment: any chance this can be updated to Python 3 esp. 3.8?

Answer (score 12):

[Alex Martelli's solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067060/translating-perl-to-python/1067151#1067151) works good, but needs some fixes and additions:

In the lines using regular expression substitution, the insertion of the matched groups must be double-escaped OR the replacement string must be prefixed with r to mark is as regular expression:

```
line = re.sub(r"([^'])'t'(.)", "\\1THIS_IS_TRUE\\2", line)
```

or

```
line = re.sub(r"([^'])'f'(.)", r"\1THIS_IS_FALSE\2", line)
```

Also, this line should be added before print:

```
line = line.replace('AUTOINCREMENT', 'AUTO_INCREMENT')
```

Last, the column names in create statements should be backticks in MySQL. Add this in line 15:

```
  sub = sub.replace('"','`')
```

Here's the complete script with modifications:

```
import re, fileinput

def main():
  for line in fileinput.input():
    process = False
    for nope in ('BEGIN TRANSACTION','COMMIT',
                 'sqlite_sequence','CREATE UNIQUE INDEX'):
      if nope in line: break
    else:
      process = True
    if not process: continue
    m = re.search('CREATE TABLE "([a-z_]*)"(.*)', line)
    if m:
      name, sub = m.groups()
      sub = sub.replace('"','`')
      line = '''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %(name)s;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %(name)s%(sub)s
'''
      line = line % dict(name=name, sub=sub)
    else:
      m = re.search('INSERT INTO "([a-z_]*)"(.*)', line)
      if m:
        line = 'INSERT INTO %s%s\n' % m.groups()
        line = line.replace('"', r'\"')
        line = line.replace('"', "'")
    line = re.sub(r"([^'])'t'(.)", "\\1THIS_IS_TRUE\\2", line)
    line = line.replace('THIS_IS_TRUE', '1')
    line = re.sub(r"([^'])'f'(.)", "\\1THIS_IS_FALSE\\2", line)
    line = line.replace('THIS_IS_FALSE', '0')
    line = line.replace('AUTOINCREMENT', 'AUTO_INCREMENT')
    if re.search('^CREATE INDEX', line):
        line = line.replace('"','`')
    print line,

main()
```

Comment: Just noticed this after copying his script and finding the same error.  (Edited the earlier answer so its now correct).

Comment: Two more corrections I required to migrate a phpBB board: 1) escabe backslash, and 2) `mediumtext(n)` --> `mediumtext`;

Comment: I had to modify this script a bit to get it to work for me (had some issues importing dates, escaped semi-colons in strings, and having the table name in quotes)  https://gist.github.com/rednebmas/df2535924bbbf7f32f3dd6040e370d15

Answer (score 8):

Here is a slightly better version of the original.

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010; # for s/\K//;

while( <> ){
  next if m'
    BEGIN TRANSACTION   |
    COMMIT              |
    sqlite_sequence     |
    CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
  'x;

  if( my($name,$sub) = m'CREATE TABLE \"([a-z_]*)\"(.*)' ){
    # remove "
    $sub =~ s/\"//g; #"
    $_ = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $name;\nCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $name$sub\n";

  }elsif( /INSERT INTO \"([a-z_]*)\"(.*)/ ){
    $_ = "INSERT INTO $1$2\n";

    # " => \"
    s/\"/\\\"/g; #"
    # " => '
    s/\"/\'/g; #"

  }else{
    # '' => \'
    s/\'\'/\\\'/g; #'
  }

  # 't' => 1
  s/[^\\']\K\'t\'/1/g; #'

  # 'f' => 0
  s/[^\\']\K\'f\'/0/g; #'

  s/AUTOINCREMENT/AUTO_INCREMENT/g;
  print;
}
```

Comment: A better way would be to actually parse the input, and output it, in the correct format.

Comment: Initially it seemed like a SQL export from sqlite would be easy enough to massage into a mysql compatible format, but the more time I spend on this the more I agree with you :)

Answer (score 8):

all of scripts on this page can't deal with simple sqlite3:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF;
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE Filename (
  FilenameId INTEGER,
  Name TEXT DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY(FilenameId) 
  );
INSERT INTO "Filename" VALUES(1,'');
INSERT INTO "Filename" VALUES(2,'bigfile1');
INSERT INTO "Filename" VALUES(3,'%gconf-tree.xml');
```

None were able to reformat "table_name" into proper mysql's `table_name` . Some messed up empty string value.

Answer (score 3):

Based on http://docs.python.org/dev/howto/regex.html ...

1. Replace `$line =~ /.*/` with `re.search(r".*", line)`.
2. `$line !~ /.*/` is just `!($line =~ /.*/)`.
3. Replace `$line =~ s/.*/x/g` with `line=re.sub(r".*", "x", line)`.
4. Replace `$1` through `$9` inside `re.sub` with `\1` through `\9` respectively.
5. Outside a sub, save the return value, i.e. `m=re.search()`, and replace `$1` with the return value of `m.group(1)`.
6. For `"INSERT INTO $1$2\n"` specifically, you can do `"INSERT INTO %s%s\n" % (m.group(1), m.group(2))`.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what is so hard to understand about this that it requires a snide remark as in your comment above. Note that `<>` is called the diamond operator. `s///` is the substitution operator and `//` is the match operator `m//`.

Answer (score 3):

Real issue is do you know actually how to migrate the database? What is presented is merely a search and replace loop.

Answer (score 1):

Shortest? The tilde signifies a regex in perl. "import re" and go from there. The only key differences are that you'll be using \1 and \2 instead of $1 and $2 when you assign values, and you'll be using %s for when you're replacing regexp matches inside strings.