# Django app deployment with sqlite database

Tags: django, sqlite, postgresql, web-applications, deployment

I'm newish to Django and am getting to the stage where I need to deploy my first app!

I'd like to understand the way to do this, given how the app is set up, particularly that we have an sqlite database (deliberately) as it's easier to ping the file around to ensure all persisted data is available to the other developers on the team. Once we deploy, users will be adding their own data which the development team will need access to on their local machines for analysis

I've looked into Heroku, but it doesn't seem to support sqlite databases.  If we move to a postgresql database for the deployed version, then how can I get the latest data off the server?

What would you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite doesn't seem to be the best solution for deployment purposes (See: [using SQLite in Django in production?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913833/using-sqlite-in-django-in-production)). If you need to analyse the data from production database on development machines, I would recommend dumping it periodically and loading on the local machine or (if the data doesn't need to be modified in any way or it's too large) just accessing the database remotely by setting access to it from development machines.

For getting data off the server you could use the `manage.py dumpdata` command
(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/django-admin/#dumpdata-appname-appname-appname-model) and then import it as fixtures (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/).