# Neccessary procedure for deploying a django app for production

Tags: android, python, ios, django, sqlite

I have developed a django app and i'am confused.

1). What is the procedure to convert the django app from development to production.

2). Once the app is available for users (ie Live on a server),How to add future development to the app without needing to upload the whole thing but just the changes and the new packages.

3)Is sqllite efficient enough to be used for servicing a large group of users and integration with android, ios apps.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1) To convert your Django app from development to production, you open your settings.py file and look for the variable `DEBUG`. Set its value to `FALSE`. Now Django won't give debugging tips if some error occurs and hence its safe for production now.

2) Use Git. One of it's purpose is to keep adding only the new things as we upgrade our app without having to upload the whole app every time. It's very convenient.

3) Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6919386/4440874) to understand which database you need.

Comment: This helped alot, can use send me any link on how to use git for updating the app

Comment: Hey, check out [this](http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/index.html) tutorial. They will teach you everything from building your Django app to deploying it on the server through Git.
And consider marking the answer as accepted if it helped :)