How do I get out the doubles of the dropdown menu?
I have a dropdown in the index.html which shows duplicate values. These are displayed if I have e.g. 2 articles with the same developer_id in index.html.
I want that if several articles with the same value for the dropdown menu are retrieved from the database, it is only displayed once in the dropdown menu. Can anyone help me with this?
view.py
def index(request):
    return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
        "auctions": Listing.objects.all()
    })

def sort_categories(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        get_category = request.POST["developer_id"]
        dev = Games.objects.get(developer=get_category)
        sortobjects = Games.objects.values(developer_id=dev).distinct()
        #sortobjects = Games.objects.values("developer_id").distinct()
        #if dev == "":
        #    messages.error(request, "Developer not in List")
        #    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("article", args=(id, )))
        get_article = Listing.objects.filter(developer_id=dev)
        all_dev = Listing.objects.all()
    #else:
        return render(request, "auctions/index.html", {
           "get_article": get_article,
           "all_dev": all_dev,
           "data": sortobjects

        })

models.py
class Comment(models.Model):
    user_comment = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="user_comment")
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True, related_name="listing_comment")
    comments = models.CharField(max_length=500)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user_comment} {self.listing} {self.comments}"

index.html
    <form action="{% url 'sort_categories' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="dev"></label>
        <!--<input type="text" name="dev" id="developer_id" placeholder="Developer">-->
        <select name="developer_id" id="developer_id"><br>
            {% for i in auctions %}
                <option value="{{ i.developer_id }}">{{ i.developer_id }}</option>
            {% endfor %}


It seems that your variable dev contains a Games instance, but you use that same variable in .filter(developer_id=dev) to search for a specific developer. That does sound like mismatched types.

can u please edit the full html page and models

+1 for what Ralf said.
Also if it's not the case, you seems to have duplicates in the database, so a constraint would solve the real issue instead of patching it by removing duplicates.
Otherwise check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50328388/using-distinct-with-filter-in-django
