# Deploying application that uses a PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, visual-studio, deployment

I have created a simple application that refers to a PostgreSQL database on my computer. How should I run my application on my friend's computer? He doesn't have the PostgreSQL database on his computer yet. Should I install PostgreSQL on his computer and create the exact same database on his computer and install my application on his computer?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this is an architectural and DevOps style question: how to do mutual development on a project, without stepping on each other's toes.  There are *many* solutions to this, and without more direct knowledge of your setup, we can only guess at what's "best."

At the end of the day, if your project relies on the DB, then your friend will need an accessible DB.  How you do that is up to you.  Before we go into Postgres-specific solutions, have you considered using a simpler SQLite setup for "just you developers", and then migrating to Postgres when preparing to deploy?  This, for example, is a strategy often used by [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/databases/) [website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913833/using-sqlite-in-django-in-production) [developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476606/django-what-are-the-best-practices-to-migrate-a-project-from-sqlite-to-postgres).

If your friend does not "speak databases," I might consider the SQLite approach.  Alternatively, you could put a DB on a shared third computer that you can administrate.  Going further, you do not necessarily need to have separate databases, provided what each of you are doing in regards to the DB will not impact each other.

In short, this best answer to this question is going to be project and developer specific.