# How can I import an sqlite database to phpMyAdmin?

Tags: sqlite, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

I have a sqlite database. I have tried to export that database and import it to phpMyAdmin in SQL format but it didn't work. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you show or explain how you tried to do it?

Comment: try using FFOX Sqlite Manager to export it into a .sql file

Comment: Here is a good overview of the differences of sqlite3 and mysql that you should care about. maybe this thread helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/87531/776219

Comment: @Joum I exported it with the sqlite Database Browser in .sql format then I made a simple import with phpmyadmin and it show me this error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRANSACTION' at line 1

Comment: Then you should read the comment from @DennisMeissner. As far as I understand, SQLite and MySQL don't use the same syntax, and as such, the way each would handle the same `.sql` file isn't consistent.

Answer (score 11):

You might want to take a look at [phpliteAdmin](https://www.phpliteadmin.org/). It looks like this:

[image]

You only need to be able to execute PHP. The whole project consists of 3 files, where one is a README, one is a config file and the other one is the real program.

Answer (score 1):

To import SQLite database into PHPMyAdmin, there are many online converters available online to convert an SQLite file to SQL. I used this one

> https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-sqlite-to-mysql-online