# converted sqlite db wont import with phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sqlite, phpmyadmin

Converted sqlite3 to mysql, but the import fails in phpMyAdmin and produces this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,`sequence` VARCHAR,`items_count` INTEGER,`total` FLOAT,`c' at line 1

What am I missing?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `orders`;
CREATE TABLE `orders` (`id` VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,`sequence` VARCHAR,`items_count` INTEGER,`total` FLOAT,`change` FLOAT,`tax_subtotal` FLOAT,`surcharge_subtotal` FLOAT,`discount_subtotal` FLOAT,`payment_subtotal` FLOAT,`rounding_prices` VARCHAR,`precision_prices` VARCHAR,`rounding_taxes` VARCHAR,`precision_taxes` VARCHAR,`status` INTEGER,`service_clerk` VARCHAR,`service_clerk_displayname` VARCHAR,`proceeds_clerk` VARCHAR,`proceeds_clerk_displayname` VARCHAR,`member` VARCHAR,`member_displayname` VARCHAR,`member_email` VARCHAR,`member_cellphone` VARCHAR,`invoice_type` VARCHAR,`invoice_title` VARCHAR,`invoice_no` VARCHAR,`invoice_count` INTEGER,`destination` VARCHAR,`table_no` INTEGER,`check_no` INTEGER,`no_of_customers` INTEGER,......
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing the data lengths of the `VARCHAR` columns.  MySQL requires a length like `VARCHAR(32)`

Comment: thank you so much! I been assigned mysql projects now and I dont know a lick about it. Knew it had to be something simple.

Answer (score 0):

There is a litte differnce between SQLite and MySQL syntax.

Below answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql)

Here a list of ALL the differences in SQL syntax that I know about between the two file formats: The lines starting with:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
COMMIT
sqlite_sequence
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
```

are not used in MySQL

```
SQLlite uses CREATE TABLE/INSERT INTO "table_name" and MySQL uses CREATE TABLE/INSERT INTO table_name
MySQL doesn't use quotes inside the schema definition
MySQL uses single quotes for strings inside the INSERT INTO clauses
SQLlite and MySQL have different ways of escaping strings inside INSERT INTO clauses
SQLlite uses 't' and 'f' for booleans, MySQL uses 1 and 0 (a simple regex for this can fail when you have a string like: 'I do, you don\'t' inside your INSERT INTO)
SQLLite uses AUTOINCREMENT, MySQL uses AUTO_INCREMENT
```

The above link will help more regarding this.

Comment: I have already tried that thread and it didn't help. Probably because my mistake was so simple it didn't need mention

Comment: @n8techy I have also faced a similar problem in past. The method which I followed was, first used export feature of :  [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) then replaced all the above mentioned keywords with MySQL equalent from the sql file.