# How to copy data from SQLite3 to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have an older Rails 3 app that use SQLite3 database. I need to switch it to MySQL - that's kind of easy-peasy.

The problem is that in the SQLite3 database is a scheme of categories - about 500. I need to export these categories from SQLite3 database and import them into the newly create MySQL one.

Now the thing is (as I haven't done it before) - how to make this kind of migration in its simplest way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql is nice answer, nothing to say more.

Answer (score 0):

sqlite3 dump file is alike mysql one so:

1. open sqlite3 and run :

   `.output filename.sql`

   `.dump`

   `.exit`
2. open filename.sql and:

   delete `PRAGMA` commands

   add 1st line `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`

   add last line `SET foreign_key_checks = 1;`
3. run in your OS:

   `mysql -u<user> -p<user> <database> < filename.sql`