# Import .db file into Msql?

Tags: mysql

I am new to hosting website and stuffs, I hosted a forum just for fun on 000webhost.com using an open source forum called Simple Machines Forum (SMF), by the time I setup the forum, I didn't know anything about database and all so I just typed random words like my username, my forum name etc. on "Database name", "Database server" fields. I think I typed my forum's link in "database server" field, so nothing was created on Mysql server and instead a database was created in the root of my website with a file format .db, so I want to import this .db to a proper Mysql server. When I opened this database with notepad++, all my posts, people usernames and file attachments were there. Can I import it?

Please let your answers be noob friendly. :D Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, but there is no really noob friendly way to answer this, because it's a complex task.

This database you have is likely in SQLite format. You can try creating a dump of it like this:

```
sqlite3 your_database.db .dump >dump.sql
```

And then feed this dump to MySQL using phpMyAdmin or MySQL workbench, or command line. But doing this directly most like won't work because of incompatibilities between SQLite and MySQL. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql) for possible solutions for this.