# Migrating sqlite3 from Django to mysql in AWS RDS always reporting syntax error

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, sqlite

I am migrating django sqlite3 to mysql in AWS RDS (I am pretty new to mysql). What I have done is:

(1) first I dump sqlite3 to sql file by `sudo sqlite3 db.sqlite3 .dump > /home/ubuntu/temp.sql`

(2) then I tried `sudo mysql -h MYRDSHOSTNAME -u MYUSERNAME -P 3306 -p mydb < temp.sql`

(3) after entering the password, I got this

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF' at line 1

I tried deleting the first line in temp.sql, but then the same error occurred and it was still pointing to line 1.

I also went check `mydb` in RDS to ensure it is actually there. And it is there (empty of course).
[image]

Version of MySQL engine on RDS is 5.6.22, and on django's computer is 5.6.19

Was there anything I overlooked or did wrong? Thank you guys very much!

Comment: SQLite3 and MySQL has slightly different grammars. Check out this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql

Comment: aha! thanks! I am now playing with the translation script.

Comment: There is a UNIQUE (xxx, yyy) in sqlite. Should I delete this in MySQL? It is said UNIQUE is not used in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
import fileinput

def this_line_is_useless(line):
    useless_es = [
        'BEGIN TRANSACTION',
        'COMMIT',
        'sqlite_sequence',
        'CREATE UNIQUE INDEX',
        'PRAGMA foreign_keys=OFF'
        ]
    for useless in useless_es:
        if re.search(useless, line):
                return True

def has_primary_key(line):
    return bool(re.search(r'PRIMARY KEY', line))

searching_for_end = False
for line in fileinput.input():
    if this_line_is_useless(line): continue

    # this line was necessary because ''); was getting
    # converted (inappropriately) to \');
    if re.match(r".*, ''\);", line):
        line = re.sub(r"''\);", r'``);', line)

    if re.match(r'^CREATE TABLE.*', line):
        searching_for_end = True

    m = re.search('CREATE TABLE "?([A-Za-z_]*)"?(.*)', line)
    if m:
        name, sub = m.groups()
        line = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %(name)s;\nCREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %(nam                                                                             e)s%(sub)s\n"
        line = line % dict(name=name, sub=sub)
    else:
        m = re.search('INSERT INTO "([A-Za-z_]*)"(.*)', line)
        if m:
                line = 'INSERT INTO %s%s\n' % m.groups()
                line = line.replace('"', r'\"')
                line = line.replace('"', "'")
    line = line.replace('AUTOINCREMENT','AUTO_INCREMENT')
    #line = line.replace('UNIQUE ','')
    line = line.replace('"','')
    line = re.sub(r"(?<!')'t'(?=.)", r"1", line)
    line = re.sub(r"(?<!')'f'(?=.)", r"0", line)

    # Add auto_increment if it's not there since sqlite auto_increments ALL
    # primary keys
    if searching_for_end:
        if re.search(r"integer(?:\s+\w+)*\s*PRIMARY KEY(?:\s+\w+)*\s*,", line):
            line = line.replace("PRIMARY KEY", "PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT")
        # replace " and ' with ` because mysql doesn't like quotes in CREATE com                                                                             mands

    # And now we convert it back (see above)
    if re.match(r".*, ``\);", line):
        line = re.sub(r'``\);', r"'');", line)

    if searching_for_end and re.match(r'.*\);', line):
        searching_for_end = False

    if re.match(r"CREATE INDEX", line):
        line = re.sub('"', '`', line)

    print line,
```

Finally, I found myself the answer. Below is my python script for translating sqlite3 dump to mysql. It is actually from [Quick easy way to migrate SQLite3 to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql) with my own modification because UINIQUE should no longer to deleted in my case (due to version update I guess). Anyway, I dump the sqlite3 using the command below and import it on the mysql side. Done.

```
sqlite3 sample.db .dump | python dump_for_mysql.py > dump.sql
```