# Migrating sqlite to mysql (guid type probleme)

Tags: mysql, sqlite, user-interface, import, export

i have big problem with GUID type in my sqlite database when i want to migrate it to mysql.

I have database sqlite, with tables contains GUID types
**in sqlite professional expert it displays as hexadecimal**

**but in Navicat premium it display as caracters**

In my mysql table i have this structure :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ul1nR.jpg)

When i migrate my data from SQLITE to MYSQL, it displays as caracters not hexadecimal.
When i export from sqlite to csv it is same issue it is not displayed as Hexadecimal format.

MY QUESTION:
How to do for exporting from Sqlite To Mysql and having in mysql Hexadecimal format as this picture
[Correct format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yd3C.png)

Thank you for your help and excuse me for my bad english

Comment: Try you use one encoding for export and import data?

Comment: I exported my data and imported it with utf8

Comment: Ok, convert your table encode to `utf8`, now you use `latin1_swedish_ci`

Answer (score 0):

Use one encode in sqlite and mysql, for example utf8. Now you use in MySQL `latin1_swedish_ci` encode, convert it to `utf8_general_ci` for example.

Comment: But when i export it to csv, it not appear same as in sqlite professional expert. it display as caracteres not as hexadecimal. can i export it as hexadecimal

Comment: you can, I think will be better if you will read this about your issue [this article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql), use some tools instead csv

Comment: I haven't get an answer for my question.

Comment: You can't use CSV, but you can use specific programs or custom scripts for that