# Can I save SQLite files to disk and then use them in another SQLite session?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sqlite

Let's say I were to open SQLite and create a table, then insert data into it and save to disk.

Could I then import this file in another SQLite session and many queries on it?

How transferable is the data format for SQLite? Does it work with MySQL and PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SQLite database file is a simple file you can connect to it from several instances.

Accessing it from MySQL or PostgreSQL directly is not possible.

But you can surely find scripts that will import the data from one to another

Comment: "But you can surely find scripts that will import the data from one to another"
Any examples?

Comment: An SQLite database file *can* be opened multiple times.

Comment: @ShanZhengYang a simple google search will do, ie http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18671/quick-easy-way-to-migrate-sqlite3-to-mysql